# Enable Cookies in a Crosswalk Cordova for Android app

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

we are trying to enable cookie storage in our Crosswalk Cordova for Android app.
We are having trouble locating the location of where we should do this?
Any directions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

In the template java file you are using (normally AppTemplateActivity.java under crosswalk folder), you need to modify it to import CookieManager and enable cookies (and/or file system cookies probably)

```
package org.xwalk.app.template;

import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;
import org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkCookieManager;
import org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkClient;

public class AppTemplateActivity extends XWalkRuntimeActivityBase {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void didTryLoadRuntimeView(View runtimeView) {
        if (runtimeView != null) {
            XWalkCookieManager mCookieManager = new XWalkCookieManager();
            mCookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
            mCookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);

            setContentView(runtimeView);
            ....
        } else {
          .....
        }
    }
```

Comment: unable to setcookie with  mCookieManager.setCookie("xxx.xxx.xxx", cookies)

Answer (score 0):

XWalkCookieManager is not supported in embedding api ... https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-3185 but I think we can set cookies by evaluateJavascript , but I did not try it yet...